# This app is optimised for iPhone 6/6 Plus

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm optimising an application to support iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus and I have some doubts.

I read a lot of articles and my first approach was to create a LaunchImages package in Images.xcassets with all the resolutions that should be supported by the application. With this approach my application has the correct resolutions for all devices and it seems to work well.
However, I read the Apple's documentation too about this subject and i noticed the following statement: "You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6. ". After some research I understood that we have another way to make the application optimised for the new iPhones that consists in the creation of a storyboard/XIB to be used as Launch Screen. I implemented this approach too but I have a problem with the resolution for iPhone 6.

**My question is:** Is it really necessary to implement the second approach to have the "This app is optimised for iPhone 6/6 Plus" in the App Store? Or the first approach gives the right too?

Thanks

Comment: No, just the correct size launch screen will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the launch images for the new iPhone 6 resolutions only (without the new launch storyboard), you will still get the "Optimized for iPhone 6".

I chose not to use the launch storyboard scene in my apps yet since I'm still supporting iOS7, which requires launch images and doesn't support the launch storyboard (iOS 7 will simply ignore the launch storyboard). My apps all say "This app is optimized for iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus."

If you decide to require iOS 8, you should consider using only the launch storyboard and drop the old launch images. Then, when new resolution devices come out, you may not need an update.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to submit the app without the storyboard once it needs to support iOS 7 as well.